# File output and race conditions

Tags: files-and-directories, output, timing

Is it possible to know when Mathematica is done writing a file?  I'm looking to automate something and I'm wanting to have Mathematica put it in a file using `Put[]`, and maybe also `Export[]`. I need to know that the file is complete before dealing with it outside Mathematica, but I don't want to have to exit Mathematica first.

How can I be ***sure*** that Mathematica is done writing the file?  Any solution is on the table, from waiting for Mathematica to reprompt, to relying on a metafile.  I'd like to avoid writing additional data to the file if at all possible, though.

Comment: What other tools/kind of tools are you working with except for Mathematica for the purpose of automating?

Comment: Stuff I'm building myself.  Perl scripts and whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

If you other tool can wait for the existence of a file, you can use a "lock" file say "C:\Temp\lock.txt"

1) Before Mathematica writes your data, use `DeleteFile["C:\\Temp\\lock.txt"]`
2) Do all the operations you need.
3) Write one byte to the lock file: `1>>"C:\\Temp\\lock.txt"`.

In the meantime, your other tool is waiting for lock file to appear. A somewhat better protocol:

1) Before Mathematica writes your data, use `FileExistsQ["C:\\Temp\\lock.txt"]` to check whether the lock file is there. If so, pause Mathematica for say 10 seconds to give time to the other tool. Loop while the file is there.
2) If the look file has been erased, have Mathematica do the required writing. Once it is done, create the lock file.
3) Rinse and repeat.

---

My answer above depends on the answer to this question:

**Does Mathematica return from a command such as `PutAppend` without finishing writing?**

I think it does not. I have no access to Mathematica's code, but the following test suggests so:

```
SetDirectory@$TemporaryDirectory;xx = Table[N[Pi, 50000], {10000}]; ByteCount[xx]
Timing[PutAppend[xx, "eraseme.txt"]; FileByteCount["eraseme.txt"]]
```

> 226000080
>
> {56.363161, 519927272}

The byte count of the last command is the correct one (as reported by the OS 3 minutes later).

Comment: And how can you be sure that the buffer flushing is done in the right order?

Comment: @belisarius: Are you telling me that there are operative systems that would report the existence of a file after it was erased? or that would not read the latest content of the main file even if it was not flushed to disk? Isn't the job of the operative system to manage buffer flushing? I do not follow your question.

Comment: No, I mean something worse: How do you know when _Mathematica_ calls the OS to write the file?

Comment: @belisarius: I expect that Mathematica would not return from the command until the operative system says it can. I do not think that Mathematica should be in the business of caching files. Also, I expect that, unless told otherwise, Mathematica  executes commands sequentially ... in the same thread. I might be mistaken in my expectations though.

Comment: All your expectations sound very reasonable, but the OP asked _"How can I be_ **sure** _that Mathematica is done writing the file?"_ (emphasis mine) :)

Comment: What belisarius said.

Comment: If you want to be 100% sure, then open the file, read its contents and compare to what you wrote. That is an overkill.

Comment: By the way, the "lock file" method is used by Firefox to prevent other Firefox copies from using the same profile at the same time.

Comment: @Hector: If I knew what I wrote, I wouldn't need to read it, would I?

Comment: @wfaulk: Mathematica knows, Perl doesn't. Mathematica checks the writing has finished by reading the back the file and comparing to what it wrote. Once Mathematica **knows for sure** that what is in the disk is what it wrote, it creates the file to signal to Perl.